# Can't activate webcam on Ubuntu (18.04.5 LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, usb, camera

I have installed the `cheese` software in order to activate the integrated webcam on my HP laptop. I get the message: `No device found`. I tried every solution that I found proposed on the Internet. Nothing worked. After typing the command `lsusb`, I got the following:

```
   Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
   Bus 002 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0018 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint scanner
   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The output of `dmesg| grep -i cam` is

> [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD

For the permissions, `ls -l /dev/video`, I get:

> ls: cannot access '/dev/video': No such file or directory

Typing in `sudo adduser $USER $(stat --format="%G" /dev/video)` I get a similar answer:

> stat: cannot stat '/dev/video': No such file or directory
> adduser: The user `ibraim' already exists.

I also tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y webcam
```

Then checked with `cheese` to unfortunately only get the result:`No device found.`

Can somebody suggest what might go wrong in my case? Many thanks.

Comment: Please provide output of `dmesg| grep -i cam`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and comment. Here is the output that I got:     [ 0.000000] AMD AuthenticAMD

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read, ignored by AskUbuntu's indexing system, and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: What is the permission/ownership of the camera? `ls -l /dev/video`. Is your userid a member of the `video` group? `id`. To join the `video` group, `sudo adduser $USER $(stat --format="%G" /dev/video)`, then logout/in. Check `id` again.

Comment: Thanks. I now edited the post. I hope that somebody will provide some suggestion.

Comment: If lsusb doesn't show your webcam it is not supported by the kernel. 8086:0189 ought to be a bluetooth adapter. All other devices aren't web cams. You could also try another distribution bootable from a usb drive, e.g. Arch Linux or Linux Mint. If these neither show the device's ID you're out of options.

Comment: Ok.Thanks. As I understand, the Ubuntu version I have is not supporting the webcam. Is there a remedy? It is too demanding to try another Linux distribution for the purpose of the webcam. Can the issue be at the webcam itself?